Calculating the end km with reference to the start km of road in QGIS
Note the labelling on the picture to be the lengths of the link segments and have been selected from Right to Left.
Start KM = KM at the beginning of the link
End KM = KM at the end of the link. (where start km of first link = 0 km, end km = (length of the link)), a
How can I calculate the start and end km of each link without manually adding the length of the previous link to the current one? The KM on the first link will be 0 KM and the end KM will be the length of the link.


WGS 84 : EPSG:4326

Not sure how to do it in QGIS, but "linear referencing" is the term for what you want to do. A quick Google search of "qgis linear referencing" turned up a lot of promising links.

Let me check it out, Thanks.

For the sake of argument, let's call the collective selected links a "route". Is this the only route you need to calculate the start and end of the links for, or are there more routes? If there are more, how are they distinguished from each other - (e.g. do they have a code with which they are grouped)?

There are more routes, basically for each 'street', i'll need to calculate the start and ends for.
Some Streets don't have street names, so they are not grouped in anyway
